# Deleting the last space in cycle, and saving the rest ones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day everyone,

I'm beginning making my first steps in python and on this stackoverflow.

I have a well-working program, it's just what I need. However, I want to ask you about cancelling the last space (noted red in picture), and saving the previous two (noted green in picture) during one cycle. Is that even possible?

I've tried to `exit()` `break` and everything else that cancelling the working processes, but they were all leading to an error.

The code is below as well.

[image]

```
cook_book = [
  ['salad',
      [
         ['potato', 100, 'g.'],
          ['carrot', 50, 'g.'],
          ['pickles', 50, 'g.'],
          ['peas', 30, 'g.'],
          ['mayonnaise', 70, 'ml.'],
      ]
  ],
  ['pizza',  
      [
         ['cheese', 50, 'g.'],
          ['tomatoes', 50, 'g.'],
          ['dough', 100, 'g.'],
          ['bacon', 30, 'g.'],
          ['salami', 30, 'g.'],
          ['mushrooms', 20, 'g.'],
          ],
  ],
  ['fruit dessert',
      [
        ['apple', 60, 'g.'],
        ['kiwi', 60, 'g.'],
        ['cottage cheese', 60, 'g.'],
        ['sugar', 10, 'g.'],
        ['honey', 50, 'ml.'],  
        ]
    ]
]
person = 5
for dishname in cook_book:
  print (dishname[0].capitalize(),':') #Writing a dish name and ":"
  for ingridients in dishname[1]:
    print(f'{ingridients[0]}, {ingridients[1]*person}{ingridients[2]}')
    #each compund, then ", " and their mass depends on person and without space it's unit
  print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to execute the last print statement only if you are not processing the last element. To check if you are in the last iteration you can use `cook_book[-1]` which gives you the last element and check if this is the current element.

```
for dishname in cook_book:
  print (dishname[0].capitalize(),':') #Writing a dish name and ":"
  for ingridients in dishname[1]:
    print(f'{ingridients[0]}, {ingridients[1]*person}{ingridients[2]}')
    #each compund, then ", " and their mass depends on person and without space it's unit
  if dishname != cook_book[-1]:
    print()
```

Comment: Since it's a list, you can have duplicate entries. It's safer to check first.